# Easy way to find which Eclipse version and plugins are needed for existing Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was given a working Eclipse project in Java. If I open it in some version of Eclipse then I get numerous errors. I get them because my version of Eclipse differs (it is not web developer) and vaadin and ivy plugins were used to create the project. How can I understand which version of Eclipse and which plugins are needed? I can get some sense by looking in .setting folder. There are a lot of files with names as namespaces related to plugins. Is there more direct or automatic/semi automatic way to find which plugins and Eclipse version are needed?

Comment: I deleted my answer as it only applies to Eclipse plugin development which I don't think is what you are asking about. There isn't really a good way to see what additional Eclipse plugins were used when developing a normal Java project.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Eclipse developers expect you to know your tools and if you take over a project from someone else or join a project, that someone explains to you how to install and configure Eclipse.

To find out which Eclipse plugins you need, look into the file `.project` and the folder `.settings`. Google for the file names and plugin IDs to see what they might mean. Usually, the third word of the name is the project (org.eclipse.jdt.* -> JDT project).

For missing classes, you need to look at the classpath. The easiest way to do that is to right-click on your project name and then select "Properties" from the menu. There is an entry "Build Path" which contains all the dependencies. Click through the tabs to see what you need.

For plugin projects, look into the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`; Eclipse should open a special editor when you open it which has a tab for dependencies.